# Filter by Dates using DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can't filter by the date in the current format (e.g. 7/8/2019). I want to be able to query the data after 7/8/2019.

This is for DB Browser for SQLite, I've been trying functions per below:

```
SELECT From_number, Body
FROM Koodos
WHERE Sent_Date > '07/08/2019';
```

I don't get an error data, but the filtering doesn't work. It just simply returns the entire database everytime.

Comment: How are the dates stored in the column `sent_date`? SQLite does not support proper data types, so everything is stored as as string. It would be better if you stored the dates as ISO dates: `2019-08-07` that makes comparing them as strings much more reliable.

Comment: Which version of Sqlite are you using?

Comment: Dates are stored as "07/08/2019" in the ***sent_date***. I guess I should change to the ISO dates to make the filtering easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sqlite **V3.7.12** or **greater**

`select From_number, Body from Koodos where Sent_Date > date('now','-1 years');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might resolve your problem.

```
select dateofbirth from customer where date(dateofbirth)>date('1980-12-01');
select * from customer where date(dateofbirth) < date('now','-30 years');
```